# How to loop through an object of arrays create views in react native?

Tags: javascript, object, react-native

So I have an object like so,

```
Object{ 2017-08-01:Array(2), 2017-08-02:Array(1) }
```

I have used the following code, to iterate through it,

```
return Object.keys(this.state.visits).map(function(key, index){
            console.log(key);
            return (
                <View style={{height: 40, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft: 10,marginTop: 10, fontWeight:'500'}}>{key}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
```

What happens is, this code, prints the 'key' perfectly in the console.log, but in the view, only the last date gets printed, and I also get an error in the console like so,

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.
>
> Check the render method of `filename`. See
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more information.

What I'm trying to achieve is as follows,

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Date1                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Record 1                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Record 2                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Date 2                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Record 1                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I got stuck on the date part, so am not being able to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you taking a look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html, which fits your need for a section based data set nicely.

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem title={item.title} />} // Your record component here.
  renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <H1 title={section.title} />} // Your date component here.
  sections={[ // homogenous rendering between sections
    {data: [...], title: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ...},
  ]}
/>
```

The above works nicely if your list rows in your sections are very similar. You can also have different component for different sections by passing in a per-section `renderItem` method:

```
<SectionList
  sections={[ // heterogeneous rendering between sections
    {data: [...], title: ..., renderItem: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ..., renderItem: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ..., renderItem: ...},
  ]}
/>
```

Also, the warning about `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` is because you are essentially returning an array of similar data, and React wants you to pass an `key` prop to help it better identify the components when rendering and re-rendering. You should pass in a `key` prop as the root of your repeating components like this `<View style={{ height: 40, flexDirection: 'row' }} key={key}>`

Answer (score 1):

You should give unique value to prop "key" inside `<View />`.

```
return Object.keys(this.state.visits).map(function(key, index){
            return (
                // Key prop
                <View key={key}>
                    <Text style={{marginLeft: 10,marginTop: 10, fontWeight:'500'}}>{key}</Text>
                    {func_record()} // return map for records
                </View>
            );
        });
...
render() {
     return (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         {your_func_name()}
     </View>);
}
```